# Search in multiple tables with priority

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, full-text-search

I could use some input on the best way to develop the following search script:

- The client got a database with multiple tables (wiki, blog, articles and so on)
- The wiki and blog got a seperate table with tags.

If a user searches on a certain (or multiple) keyword(s) the script first has to check if there is an exact match on these tags (where a wiki has priority over a blog). These matches should show up first in the results.

Then it has to check if there is a match on the title (where again a wiki has priority over a blog, the blog over articles, etc). The last step is to check the relevancy in the content of the tables.

At the moment we just do a fulltext search on the tables with a priority factor for the titles, but this does not take into account 1) the priority for tags 2) the priority for wiki over blog articles (and so on).

Is there an efficient way to solve this?

Comment: The answer to your question is probably "yes".  Can you show the query that is currently being used for the full text search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my head, a few starting points:

## Chaining Queries

The pretty much most simple solution would be to just do a lot of queries (match wiki tags, then match blog tags, then match wiki title, then match blog title, ...) but that probably wouldn't be very efficient.

Depending on your table structures, you could speed this up a bit by mashing everything into a single query using [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html) statements and ordering that, but I imagine this would look really bad in code.

## Building a search index

If all you want is a full-word match (so "and" matches "here and there" but not "in my hands") you could also build your own search index.

In its most simple form, that would be another table with, for example, those columns:

- **keyword**: this should obviously be an index (but not a unique one) and holds the search term
- **source type**: this indicates what type of content this is (blog article, wiki page, ...) and it could either be a string or an integer (which would make ordering more easy)
- **source ID**: this is the primary key in the respective content table, e.g. die blog article ID or the wiki page ID
- **match type**: indicates where the keyword appears, for example 0 = tag, 1 = title, 2 = content

Now, whenever new content is added, you have to dissect it and feed the search index with it. You would split the title and content into single words and add each as a new row into the search index table (with match type = 1 or 2, respectively) and also add each tag (as match type = 0). The same goes for updated content, only you have to remove its old search index entries first. For the initial building and if something goes wrong, you should also have a "re-build search index completely" routine.

Your search engine now only has to use the new search table which should be reasonably efficient. You can also do further optimizations by setting this table up as an in-memory table, use another database engine or whatever you come up with.

## Use Lucene

Depending on your requirements, you could also look into [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/), which is a great search library that has its own query language and is really fast even for huge data sets.

There is also a PHP implementation of this ([ZendSearch](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSearch)), but when I tried it a while ago, it wasn't fast enough for me.

In my last project I used Lucene along with [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), which serves as a REST frontend for Lucene. I had it running on a Tomcat server that only listened to 127.0.0.1. There is a PECL extension for using Solr servers: http://pecl.php.net/package/solr

Of course, that's quite a lot to set up (needs a full Java environment, a memory-consuming application server and a PHP extension) and also a lot to learn, but it's a really powerful solution that scales the best.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. The Lucene option might be a good option for the future. I think we will go for the search index table. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling what kind of app this is.
If it's a web app shooting different queries to the server asynchronously could be a simple solution. Send the most important queries first, they are in all likelihood also the fastest queries. Update the displayed results when the data comes back.

The downside is that you will have overlapping result sets. Filtering that by ID is not a probelm, but the server is sending back too much data. Only you can tell how (un)important that is.